# CakePHP - own functions

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-2.0

Long story short: I’m integrating the Facebook API (PHP-SDK) with CakePHP (I know that there are already existing integrations out there on GitHub but I use this exercise as a learning curve for CakePHP and MVC in general). My question is the following:

I have a controller action that returns a list of friends, in a very simplistic format:

```
$data = array(
  'friends' => $this->_facebook->api('/me/friends')
);
$this->set($data);
```

`$data` is then being sent to the corresponding view where at the moment I’m simply calling `print_r($friends);` and that works like a charm. However, I’d like to order the friends array both ascending and descending, and before the MVC world, I was using this function:

```
public function listFriends($sort = "") {
        $sort = strtolower($sort);
        $friend_array = $this->_facebook->api('/me/friends');
        $friends = array();
        switch ($sort) {
            case "asc":
                foreach($friend_array['data'] as $friend) {
                    $friends[$friend['id']] = $friend['name'];
                }
                natcasesort($friends);
                return $friends;
                break;

            case "desc":
                foreach($friend_array['data'] as $friend) {
                    $friends[$friend['id']] = $friend['name'];
                }
                arsort($friends);
                return $friends;
                break;

            default:
                foreach($friend_array['data'] as $friend) {
                    $friends[$friend['id']] = $friend['name'];
                }
                return $friends;
        }
    }
```

My question is: how can I achieve the same in CakePHP, where can I place my ‘custom’ `listFriends()` function? It’s my understanding that if I place this into the controller, then someone can potentially access it by calling **http://example.com/controller/listFriends**, which I would obviously like to avoid. I also assume that the **.ctp** file is not the best place for this code to be placed, so where then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components is the answer!

Should anyone run into the same 'issue':

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class SortComponent extends Component {
    public function listFriends() {
        //blablablabla
    }
}
?>
```

And in your controller add the following:

```
public $components = array('Sort');
```

and you can access your method by calling

```
$this->Sort->listFriends()
```

Cheers!